# Возможно ли загружать в iframe любые сайты?

Tags: html, iframe

Есть страница сайта. На ней есть блок с шапкой, ниже идет iframe. В фрейм загружается главная страница разных сайтов.

Сам код iframe выглядит следующим образом:

```
<iframe src="<?= $_GET['linkdemopage'];?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

В `<?= $_GET['linkdemopage'];?>` соответственно приходит ссылка на другой сайт.

При успешной загрузке страница загружается, не все сайты. Большенство страниц выглядит следующим образом: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Если сайт будет возвращать заголовок:

```
x-frame-options  SAMEORIGIN
```

То сайт не будет отображаться в iframe.

Варианты заголовка:

> **deny** не загружать страницу вообще.
>
> **sameorigin** не загружать, если источник не совпадает.
>
> **allow-from: ДОМЕН** можно указать домен, с которого страница может быть загружена во фрейме.

Например такое делается через htaccess (если Apache) и тп.:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

Конкретно `ru.stackoverflow.com` возвращает такой заголовок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `@AlexanderSemikashev` я правильно понимаю, что загружать все сайты не получиться и причина тому заголовки, верно?

Comment: @Kyper Да вы верно поняли, сайт возвращает заголовок с запретом на отображение в iframe. Вроде как есть способы обхода, но я не интересовался ими.

Comment: @Kyper НО отмечу, что если сайт будет возвращать такой заголовок, то сайт не будет отображаться в вебвизоре яндекс метрики. То есть даже в яндексе не предпринимают никаких действий.