# Как вызвать гугл календарь на своем сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar

я недавно столкнулся проблемой использование гугл календаря на своем сайте через iFrame. С начала броузер не разрешал вызвать гугл календаря через iFrame с ошибкой x-option-frame header я установил разширения для браузер проблема решено все работал. Но сейчас есть проблема при изменении мероприятии возникает ошибка 
"Blocked a frame with origin "https://calendar.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame" 
как мне правильно использовать гугл календарь на своем сайте всеми функциями?

Comment: Google календарь нельзя во фрейме открыть, он передаёт заголовок x-frame-options  SAMEORIGIN.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-iframe-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b/922368#922368

Comment: да проблему с  x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN решал с разширениям для браузер https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iframe-allow/gifgpciglhhpmeefjdmlpboipkibhbjg с ним все отображается все работает но только редактирования мероприятии нет. Ну как та я могу вызвать и пользоватся с календарем или это не возможно ?